# Segmentation fault with variable function arguments

Tags: c, variables, segmentation-fault, arguments

My program compiles without error, but when I run it, it quits with a segmentation fault after I input a value such a radius.

I have it constructed to take a variable amount of arguments, but I suspect it could be something to do with the way I call each argument during the operation of the "shape_area" function.

Can anybody help explain what I am doing wrong here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

double shape_area(double shapetype, ...);

int main(void)
{
    int shapetype;
    double radius, side, length, width, area;

    printf("\n\nPlease enter the type of shape you wish to get the area of:\n");
    printf("| 1-Circle | 2-Square  | 3-Rectangle |\n");
    scanf("%d", &shapetype);

    // Circle
    if(shapetype == 1)
    {
        printf("\nPlease enter the radius of your circle: ");
        scanf("%lf", &radius);
        area = shape_area(shapetype, radius);
    }

    // Square
    else if(shapetype == 2)
    {
        printf("\nPlease enter the side length of your square: ");
        scanf("%lf", &side);
        area = shape_area(shapetype, side);
    }

    // Rectangle
    else if(shapetype == 3)
    {
        printf("\nPlease enter the side length of your square: ");
        scanf("%lf", &length);
        printf("\nPlease enter the side length of your square: ");
        scanf("%lf", &width);
        area = shape_area(shapetype, length, width);
    }

    else
    {
        printf("\n\nInvalid Input!\n");
        return (0);
    }

    printf("\n\nArea of Shape: %lf\n\n", area);

    return (0);

}

double shape_area(double shapetype, ...)
{
    va_list args;

    double temparea;
    double radius;
    double side;
    double length;
    double width;

    radius = va_arg (args, double);
    side = radius;
    length = radius;
    width = va_arg (args, double);

    if(shapetype == 1)
    {
        temparea = M_PI*radius*radius;
    }

    if(shapetype == 2)
    {
        temparea = side*side;
    }

    if(shapetype == 3)
    {
        temparea = length*width;
    }

    va_end (args);
    return temparea;
}
```

Comment: why not use `double shape_area(double shapetype, double radius, double width)`

Comment: Can you give sample input? My first try running it exited normally with an incorrect answer, but no segfaults.

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger to help you find the problem? It's perfectly suited for these scenarios.

Comment: It is worth noting that this function would normally be a poor way to satisfy the functional requirements (as I said in an answer), but that it is explicitly demanded in an exercise. If you are (one is) not required to do it like this, don't!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize the args list using [va_start](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdarg/va_start/)

```
double shape_area(double shapetype, ...)
{
va_list args;
va_start(args,shapetype);
.
.
```

Comment: You are dead right, I knew I missed something basic. All my friends have gone to bed and my programming exam is tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: ... and then, examine the arguments within each `if`, instead of trying to generalise them. Square and circle do not have the `width` argument.

Comment: @Snoviet before you go to bed please "accept" this answer!

Answer (score 1):

warzon correctly pointed out that you need to use va_start, but here's how to figure out what's going on in the future:

```
# The -g is the important part here, -O0 will help too if you don't care about optimization.
$ gcc -Wall -std=gnu99 -O0 -Wextra -Werror -g -foptimize-sibling-calls -o shape shape.c
$ gdb ./shape
...
(gdb) b shape_area # Set a breakpoint.
Breakpoint 1 at 0x80485b8: file shape.c, line 63.
(gdb) run
Please enter the type of shape you wish to get the area of:
| 1-Circle | 2-Square  | 3-Rectangle |
1
Please enter the radius of your circle: 3
63         radius = va_arg (args, double);
(gdb) next # Run the line that assigns the radius.
65         side = radius;
(gdb) p radius
$1 = 0
```

You'll either hit the segfault before there, or see an incorrect value for your va_arg. That leads to the man page for va_args, which states:

> The argument ap is the va_list ap initialized by va_start().

That ought to lead to the aha moment, since you forgot to call va_start(). In general, if you're getting a segfault, the first thing to do is fire up a debugger. It will most likely point you right at the problem.

Answer (score -1):

What you are doing wrong is, in my opinion, jamming all the different formulae into one function. Of course, @warzon is right that you need `va_start` in this case, but I see no advantage to this approach, unless, conceivably, you are required by the question to use it. Most of the shared code in `shape_area` relates to the overhead of the `va_list` mechanism!

If you want to pass around information about a shape of one of a number of types (and you can’t use inheritance because C is not OO), you would be better to create a `struct` or a `union` of `struct`s. In your programme, however you could just as well make `circle_area`, `square_area`, `rectangle_area` and call the appropriate one. This also obviates the need to document that `shapetype` argument!

Comment: This looks a lot like a homework problem to me. I suspect part of the assignment is "use a variadic function."

Comment: @nmichaels: you are quite likely right, but what a shame to get people into such habits. Something like a simplified `printf` or concatenating strings until you see a `NULL` would be preferable!

Comment: Indeed, I'm afraid using 1 function and in this manner is specified in this question. I would use an array myself (as I initially did, and failed to meet the question requirements) and a struct would of course work as well. From my reading on other sites, I find that variadic functions are discouraged. My lecturer often uses strange style such as recursive main functions in order to teach us what C can do. But ilike you say I believe this is not good practice.